# Setting Parent Page to Post

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, url-rewriting, seo

Does anyone know how to achieve different parent pages for posts?

I've managed to code a Custom Post Type that sits under a specific parent page, but I want the option to change this from post to post.

Example;

- `/page-1/custom-post-1/`
- `/page-1/custom-post-2/`
- `/page-2/custom-post-3/`
- `/page-2/custom-post-4/`

The final result would be URL structure like the above, but all posts sitting on one archive page.

I know by default this isn't possible as posts are non-hierarchical.

Thanks

Comment: Set the `hierarchical` parameter to `true` in your `register_post_type` args. You will get the option to select parent post in post edit scree,

Comment: are you asking how to set up the UI? Or is it the permalinks you're asking about? Or are you starting from scratch? WP assumes if a post type has hierarchy that its parent is of the same type but this is just an assumption and not enforced in the DB, and even used by WP itself for attachments and revisions etc, though the default rewrite rules weren't always written for this.

Comment: Hey @TomJNowell, it's more for the permalinks and redirects. Coding the UI isn't a problem, but it's just ensuring the URL structure comes out as intended.

Comment: Hey @Abhik, that would only allow me to set a parent of the same post type. I want my custom post type to have a parent page.

Comment: is this a page the user has chosen or is this page something you created with a page template listing your post types? AKA are you trying to build a post type archive on a page with a page builder but now your custom posts have the wrong URL?

Comment: Yes the parent page will need to be selected by the user, this will dictate the URL structure i.e. /chosen-page/custom-post-type/ the archive page isn't too much of an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be in a comment, but can't format much in there.

1. Create a relationship between your CPT and Page. For example, create a custom taxonomy for your CPT and programatically add the pages as terms. Or, you can even create a meta field.
2. Create a placeholder for the URL while registering the CPT. For example `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '%cpttag%'),`.
3. `str_replace` the placeholder with page slug you get from term/meta using [`post_type_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/).
4. Flush the permalinks (Just hitting Save on Permalinks Settings page will do it)